# Removed Firebase Database and app crashed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I removed some "tables" from my database I thought they will be created automatically after user log in first time. But now my app if full of null pointer exceptions. What is the better way to solve that problem?

Here is the code

```
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Here is the error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.borisruzanov.russianwives.App: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5406)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
                  at com.borisruzanov.russianwives.App.onCreate(App.java:34)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5403)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: are you getting null pointer on some array list.? or after deleting user node.? try my tutorial
https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Firebase-Helper/tree/master/app/src/main/java/inc/droidflick/firebasetutorial

Answer (score 1):

The error message is this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

This means your call to `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` is returning null.  That means no one is logged into your app at the time of the method call.  This likely has nothing to do with any sort of data restructuring you performed in your database.  Make sure you only call `getCurrentUser()` if you know a user is logged in, or check it for null so you can choose not to call methods on that null.

Comment: Yeah, I think it has to check logging in the beginning . But it was working well before I delete all data from database. After that, it crashes.

Comment: yes but it doesn't work because all my code is based on this instances. So I removed this part of code and null pointer on next instance and next and next. I need somehow create that table before compile i guess